# Remove new line from char string c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, char

I've been trying to remove the new line at the end of a char string. This is what I have been using.

```
char username[256];
recv(c->sock, username, sizeof username, 0);
username[strlen(username)-1] = 0;
c->SetName(username);
```

This is not working for me since the char string gets somehow deleted in half. On the other hand if I don't try to remove the new line at the end of the username I get the string with no problem. I have tried a lot of methods and I get the same result with all of them. Thanks.

Comment: _"the char string gets somehow deleted in half"_ That's unclear. Can you give _actual_ inputs and _actual_ outputs?

Comment: If the username is gustavo then the output would be: tavo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `strlen` with `recv` - `recv` returns the number of bytes read. Therefore, you can just do

```
char username[256];
int n = recv(c->sock, username, sizeof(username) - 1, 0); // recv here leaves room for a null terminator
if(n < 0) {
    /* recv error: you should handle this since it probably means the socket is closed */
    exit(1);
}
username[n] = 0; // make sure that input is null-terminated
if(n >= 1 && username[n-1] == '\n')
    username[n-1] = 0; // strip newline
setName(username);
```

Comment: I tried this and now I'm getting nothing. I always print the username inside arrow heads and now I am getting this: 
<>
Before I was getting this:
<gustavo\n>
Having in mind that gustavo is the username

Comment: I think the problem may be that you are getting `\r\n` (carriage-return new-line). Stripping the `\n` leaves a bare `\r` which may clear the input line.

Comment: should I try to strip the \r and then strip the \n ?

Comment: You should probably check first that there's a `\r` in there. You can use `strchr` or similar to find it.

Comment: @Gustavo Dos Santos - The main thing is to *LOOK AT THE BYTES BEING RETURNED FROM THE SOCKET READ*. Everything else is conjecture.   I'd recommend using a debugger.  Please update your post with this information.

Comment: After debugging I found out that the username had '\r\n' at the end, the I did 
   `if (username[strlen(username) - 1] == '\n')
        username[strlen(username) - 1] = '\0';
    if (username[strlen(username) - 1] == '\r')
        username[strlen(username) - 1] = '\0';`
that worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Did you send the '\0' C string delimiter in your socket write?  "strlen()" won't work properly unless you did.

SUGGESTION: Examine the bytes in "username" after your socket read:

1) Make sure it actually has '\n',

2) Make sure it has a '\0' C string delimiter, and make sure it's where you expect the end of string to be.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

```
  char username[256];
  int iret = recv(c->sock, username, sizeof username, 0);
  if (iret < 0) {
     <<handle error>>
  }
  if (username[iret-2] == 0x0d) {
    username[iret-2] = 0;
  } else if (username[iret-1] == '\n') {
    username[iret-1] = 0;
  }
  ...
```

But *PLEASE DON'T GUESS*.  Please look at the *ACTUAL INPUT* first.

And please don't use "strlen()" or any similar C string function until you're sure the string is delimited.  Either because you sent "0", or because you put it there.

See also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: I am sure it has '\n' but I am not so sure it has the '\0' delimiter. Let me give it a try.